# django many to many symmetrical recursive through inheritance solution

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

A lot was said about django's `ManyToMany` recursive through symmetrical "pick two" limitation.
The best solution I could find online was [Charles Leifer](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/)'s symmetric relation implementation by manually creating links in both directions (by implementing `add_relationship` and `remove_relationship`, and many other methods).

Although this is a valid implementation, I'm considering doing something a bit different. My question then would be wether what I'm trying to do is a good or bad idea? Additionally, any suggestions on how to improve this would be most appreciated!

This is it: 
Let `Instance` be a recursively relating object, and `matches` it's many to many field.
I noticed `matches` has an `@property` object called `through`, and accessing it returns an object of type `Instance_matches`.

I'd like to inherit from `Instance_matches` in a new model object we'll call `MatchDetails`, creating a [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) and manually making sure I create a `MatchDetails` object for every `Instance_matches`.

Then, I could always get the extra attributes I originally wanted `matches` to have, by doing `instance.matches.matchdetails`.

I did not try doing that, and would update on results after i get some community scrutiny.

Thanks!